SKAction completion closure error: Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter
I'm trying to call a function that takes in an Array as a reference
spill(pool: &objectPool)

And the function will make the array pops its first element to run some animations. Once the animation is complete, the element gets put back to the Array
    func spill(pool: inout [Object]) {
        let spill = pool[0]
        spriteComponent.node.addChild(spill.sprite)
        pool.removeFirst()
        spill.sprite.run(SKAction.sequence([spill.spriteAnimation, SKAction.removeFromParent()])) {
            pool.append(spill)

            //Do some other works
        } 
    }

However, I get the following error message:
Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'pool'

How do I get this function to work?
Thanks in advance.

You simply can't capture an inout parameter in an escaping closure. This is because the function will have already returned before the closure executes. It is essentially the same as trying to return a value from a closure. Personally I would never use inout anyway unless there is a very good reason.  You need to refactor to eliminate the inout. You could adopt async/await or you could provide a closure to spill and invoke that closure from the run closure.

That makes sense, thank you.
